org-mode - disable auto indent 2 space from org-babel block after press return key
I have an org-mode file as below:
#+begin_src sh :results silent
tee script.js <<EOF
Java.perform(function() {
    console.log("hello")
})
EOF
#+end_src


Then I open it with emacs -q demo.org
If i press return at the beginning of Java, then the whole code block has been ident two space like below:
#+begin_src sh :results silent
  tee script.js <<EOF

  Java.perform(function() {
      console.log("hello")
  })
  EOF
#+end_src


That's very werid behavior, how to disable such auto indention?

Turn off electric-indent-mode.

RET at that place is bound to org-return whose doc string says:
...
(org-return &optional INDENT ARG INTERACTIVE)
...
When optional INDENT argument is non-nil, call
‘newline-and-indent’ with ARG, otherwise call ‘newline’ with ARG
and INTERACTIVE.
...

In this case, INDENT is nil, so it calls newline with ARG which is also nil and INTERACTIVE which is 1.
Now check the doc string of newline:
...
If ‘electric-indent-mode’ is enabled, this indents the final new line
that it adds, and reindents the preceding line.
...

So in order to avoid this behavior, you need to turn off electric-indent-mode: do M-x electric-indent-mode (which toggles the mode: turns it off if it's on and vice versa), make sure that the message in the echo area shows that the mode is disabled, and try the whole thing again.

Awesome, which usecase need this mode? add two more space for all lines looks not good for programmer.

You should do C-h f electric-indent-mode: the doc string describes what it does. Note also that if you want the mode enabled in general, but want to turn it off in a specific buffer, you should use electric-indent-local-mode in that buffer.
